# Flex mobile: waiting view is rendered before pushing the new view

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, flex4.6

This is a big problem I have, especially with non-embedded images:
After a navigator.pushView some elements are rendered DURING and AFTER the transition is occurring. Causing transition jittering and the page re-composing after the transition.
The most simple example is `<s:BitmapImage source="xxxx" />` that renders just after the transition is complete.
But also any heavy code may cause the transition to jitter.

Is there any way to HOLD the new view and PUSH it only when some conditions are satisfied?

I know images can be embedded, but there are a lot of other situations where I really wish I could push the new view only when all the tasks are done.

Thanks for any help

Alfonso